# How to assign column data to rows in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to assign data of column in one table to rows in another table
For example consider the two tables below
Table 1 has the below structure(3 columns qid,question,result) and values

```
qid  question   result
1   question1   apple
1   question2   banana
1   question3   carrot
2   question1   mango
2   question2   orange
2   question3   popaya
```

Table 2 has the below structure(5 columns) and values

```
qid grade   test    question1   question2   question3
1    A     test1      NULL        NULL       NULL
2    B     test2      NULL        NULL       NULL
```

In the table 2 for the columns question1,question2,question3. I want to assign values of result column based on the qid.

Is this a possible scenario? if yes,how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table2
SET question1 = (select top 1 result from table1 t1 where t1.qid = qid AND question = 'question1'),
question2 = (select top 1 result from table1 t1 where t1.qid = qid AND question = 'question2'),
question3 = (select top 1 result from table1 t1 where t1.qid = qid AND question = 'question3')
```

Note: From a DB design perspective, Table2 is not ideal.  Instead, you should have something like this:

```
TABLE test
   - testID
   - testName
   - grade

TABLE question
   - testID
   - questionID
   - result
```

Table `Test` maps all the questions to the same test, so you don't need separate columns for question1, question2, question3.  After all, what happens when you have a test with 200 questions?  Do you want to add 200 columns to your table2?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly changed Query. With testing:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
qid INT,
question NVARCHAR(30),
result NVARCHAR(30)
) 

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
qid INT,
grade NVARCHAR(2),
test NVARCHAR(10),
question1 NVARCHAR(20),
question2 NVARCHAR(20),
question3 NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @table
        ( qid, question, result )
VALUES  ( 1, -- qid - int
          N'question1', -- question - nvarchar(30)
          N'apple'  -- result - nvarchar(30)
          ),
        ( 1, -- qid - int
          N'question2', -- question - nvarchar(30)
          N'banana'  -- result - nvarchar(30)
          ),
        ( 1, -- qid - int
          N'question3', -- question - nvarchar(30)
          N'carrot'  -- result - nvarchar(30)
          ),
        ( 2, -- qid - int
          N'question1', -- question - nvarchar(30)
          N'mango'  -- result - nvarchar(30)
          ),
        ( 2, -- qid - int
          N'question2', -- question - nvarchar(30)
          N'orange'  -- result - nvarchar(30)
          ),
        ( 2, -- qid - int
          N'question3', -- question - nvarchar(30)
          N'popaya'  -- result - nvarchar(30)
          )

INSERT INTO @table2
        ( qid ,
          grade ,
          test
        )
VALUES  ( 1 , -- qid - int
          N'A' , -- grade - nvarchar(2)
          N'test1' -- test - nvarchar(10)
        ),
        ( 2 , -- qid - int
          N'B' , -- grade - nvarchar(2)
          N'test2' -- test - nvarchar(10)
        )

SELECT * FROM @table
SELECT * FROM @table2
```

Here the actual Statement:

```
UPDATE @table2 SET
question1 = (SELECT TOP 1 result FROM @table t WHERE t.qid = t2.qid AND question = N'question1'),
question2 = (SELECT TOP 1 result FROM @table t WHERE t.qid = t2.qid AND question = N'question2'),
question3 = (SELECT TOP 1 result FROM @table t WHERE t.qid = t2.qid AND question = N'question3')
FROM @table2 t2
```

The result:

```
SELECT * FROM @table2
```